# How to setting cropping size in CascadeCalssifier with Java

Tags: java, image, opencv, face-detection, cascade-classifier

```
public BufferedImage detectAndDisplay(BufferedImage img, CascadeClassifier faceCascade) {
    Mat frameGray = new Mat();
    BufferedImage imgout = null;

    Mat image = ImagePreProcessing.bufferedImageToMat(img);

    // -- Detect faces
    MatOfRect faces = new MatOfRect();
    faceCascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces);

    List<Rect> listOfFaces = faces.toList();
    for (Rect face : listOfFaces) {
        Point center = new Point(face.x + face.width / 2, face.y + face.height / 2);
        Imgproc.ellipse(image, center, new Size(face.width / 2, face.height / 2), 0, 0, 360,
                new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);

        Mat faceROI = image.submat(face);
        imgout = ImagePreProcessing.Mat2BufferedImage(faceROI);
        System.out.println("OpenCV: " +center);

    }
    return imgout;
}
```

that code I have..but I don't know where the code for setting crop output image. 
I want to have the picture like original version with circle template..NOT to be crop
Can give me suggestion, please:)

input: [image: input]

output: [image: output]

Comment: Your question is not clear, what are you asking, at the end what result do you want to get?

Comment: Thank you for your attention @BahramdunAdil .I want NOT the picture to be crop. I want the picture still in its size (size_input = size_output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you returned a cropped image of the original image, so if you want the original image, draw the circle and convert it to the BufferedImage and return.

```
for (Rect face : listOfFaces) {
        Point center = new Point(face.x + face.width / 2, face.y + face.height / 2);
        Imgproc.ellipse(image, center, new Size(face.width / 2, face.height / 2), 0, 0, 360,
                new Scalar(255, 0, 255), 3);

        // dot not crop!!!
        /*Mat faceROI = image.submat(face);
        imgout = ImagePreProcessing.Mat2BufferedImage(faceROI);*/

        System.out.println("OpenCV: " +center);
        imgout = ImagePreProcessing.Mat2BufferedImage(image);

    }
```